# Batch inserts in sqlite3 - Memory Issues

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, memory, sqlite

I have two databases which I'm reading/updating from nodejs. One has news articles in HTML, and the other is used for storing the clean text version of the same articles. I currently have a script (code below) which reads from the html db, extracts the clean text, and saves it to the text db.

The problem I have is that, while this script works for a limited number of rows, when I try to run it on the whole db it ends up eating the whole memory (+7GB).

I've noticed that all inserts are actually performed together in the end, so I think I need to perform inserts on the run so that memory can be freed while still reading rows from the html db.

Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks!

```
/**
 *  Process all articles; extract text from html and save to database.
 */
dbText.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS articles (url string primary key, headline text, subhead text, copy text)");
dbHtml.each("SELECT * FROM articles", function(err, row) {
  processArticle(row.url, row.content, dbText);
});

/**
 *  Function called on each article.
 */
function processArticle(url, content, dbText) {
  $ = cheerio.load(content);
  var headlineElem = $(...);
  var subheadElem = $(...);
  var copyElem = $(...);

  var headlineText = headlineElem.length > 0 ? headlineElem.text() : "";
  var subheadText = subheadElem.length > 0 ? subheadElem.text() : "";
  var copyText = copyElem.length > 0 ? getTextWithSpaces(copyElem.get(0)) : "";

  if (!headlineText) log(url, "Headline is emtpy.");
  if (!subheadText) log(url, "Subhead is emtpy.");
  if (!copyText) log(url, "Copy is emtpy.");

  var statement = dbText.prepare("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO articles VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
  statement.run(url, headlineText, subheadText, copyText);
  statement.finalize();
}
```